# CSS :hover selector not working - why?

Tags: css, hover

This is my CSS:

```
.add-to-cart button.button > span:hover {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

It just wont work on hover. If I put the `font-size: 14px;` inside the selector without `:hover`, it works and the font size is changed, so why not on hover?

Unfortunately I can not share the markup, is a local installation only so far.

Thanks!

Comment: `.add-to-cart button.button:hover  span {
    font-size: 14px;
}`

it will do the trick for you.
`<span>` is not a `block` element i.e. why your `:hover` will only work when you `:hover` on `<span>` itself.

Comment: vivekkupadhyay solution **did the trick**, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can try to add !important to your style in order to set the priority on the other style rules:

```
.add-to-cart button.button > span:hover {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

If it doesn't work you probably should check your selector, in this case you can try to add the style to all the span tags (just to be sure that the selector is correct):

```
span:hover {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```